# Create a new folder in 'images' when installing module

Tags: installation, custom-module, images, carousel

I'm working on a basic module to display an image carousel.  The module itself works well, but what I want to do now is create a new folder called 'carousel' within the root 'images' folder when the module installs.

I've researched this a lot here (I apologise if this is a duplicate question) and from searches, but no matter what I try I can't get it to work.

I have this in the manifest file.

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

And I've created a script.php file.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

  class mod_CarouselInstallerScript
  {
    function install($parent) 
    {
      $destination = JPATH_SITE.'/'."images";
      $folder_name = "carousel";
      JFolder::create($destination .'/'. $folder_name, 0755);
    }
  }
?>
```

I've tried various versions of this found here and in Joomla documentation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's even being executed? Can you try adding `var_dump('foobar');` inside the function and check your Network tab in the browser console to see if you see that being returned?

Comment: Hi @Lodder, thank you for your reply.  I've done as you suggested and, no it's not returned in the Network tab in the browser console.

Comment: In which case your class name may be incorrect. Can you provide the XML `<name>` value for your module?

Comment: Hi @Lodder - here it is - <name>RRM Carousel</name>

Comment: Try replacing `class mod_CarouselInstallerScript` with `class mod_Rmg_carouselInstallerScript`

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you provide the entire XML file (without the `<config>` block)

Comment: I changed class to - class mod_RRM_carouselInstallerScript and it now works perfectly!  Thank you so much for all your help @Lodder

Comment: One thing I'm very curious about.  After changing the class as above the script.php file works perfectly now.  The module I created works as expected but the Helper class I used is - class ModCarouselHelper - shouldn't that be changed too?  Thanks again for all your help @Lodder, it really is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's quite possible that the `helper.php` and `script.php` use different naming conventions for the class. I'm not quite sure. Please could you add the solution as a proper answer and mark it as accepted so other know it has been solved...thank you :)

Comment: Yes, I want to accept your solution and mark it as the answer but I can't see how to do that, there's no option to do so.  Sorry if I've missing something obvious.

Comment: You can write the **answer** in the big text box below. We've been writing **comments**, not answers, which is why you can't "accept" it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Lodder for providing a solution, very much appreciated.

@Lodder suggested my class name may be incorrect and said to try 'replacing class mod_CarouselInstallerScript with class mod_Rmg_carouselInstallerScript'.

I changed my class to mod_RRM_carouselInstallerScript which solved the problem.